# Alterando como é exibido o forms.ValidationError em Django

Tags: python, django

É possível alterar a forma como o `ValidationError` é exibido? Eu notei que o *Django* cria uma tag `<ul>` e dentro dela uma tag `<li>` com o erro. Eu posso alterar a forma como isso é feito? E caso eu queira mudar a classe desses elementos, como faria?

Estou tentando fazer isso na autenticação do *Django*, dei uma olhada no código fonte e no `django.contrib.auth.forms` no form `AuthenticationForm`(apenas a parte relacionada com a exibição do erro) está assim:

```
 error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),

 def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username is not None and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
        else:
            self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

    return self.cleaned_data


 def get_invalid_login_error(self):
        return forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
            code='invalid_login',
            params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode acessar a lista de erros na sua template. Por exemplo, pra criar tags `h1` com os erros de um campo `name` do formulário:

```
{% if form.name.errors %}
    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
        <h1 class="header-erro">{{ error }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```